# MsBuild Web deploy ERROR_FILE_IN_USE

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I have a TFS build using Web Deploy to publish changes to a high traffic website. Build places an  AppOffline.htm when it starts. A lot of times build fails due to some dll file in use. Tried recycling app pool and stating/stop website before build, still fails.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4255): Web deployment task failed. (The file 'xxx.dll' is in use.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.)
```

Only way to publish successfully is to stop the website for whole duration while publish is going on.

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41463700/5006880)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any files marked read only.

Some have said anti-virus can occasional cause this error as well.  Try ignoring your web files.

Comment: Anti virus seems to be the cause. Excluding deployment folder from antivirus scan fixed the issue.

Comment: Did it work in the long-term ? I'm trying this solution because we have this error randomly for a few month and Microsoft's solution (using pubxml configuration "EnableMSDeployAppOffline") did not work. We have this error on .NET core 3.1 / 5 only, not on our apps using .NET 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing an issue where a VS2015 Web Publish to an Azure Web App has recently started to throw an error advising that a DLL file is locked...
See
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1607#issuecomment-272504519