# How to not get "ERROR_FILE_IN_USE " error when deploying a ASP.NET Core website using FTP/shared folder?

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8

I have an `ASP.NET Core RTM` Web Application that targets  `.net framework 4.52`

In my `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },
```

When I publish it to an folder it creates a `MyWebApplication.exe` and when I access the app in my browser the exe is run.

I need to publish the website to  a web server that has `Windows Server 2012` and `IIS8`

I have shared folder access via VPN to the website deploy directory.

The first time I publish the site to the folder it worked correctly. I access the website url and the site loads. However when I want to republish the website after making changes and copying over the files it tells me the `MyWebApplication.exe` is in use and the publish fails.

The only way I know how to resolve this is to before publishing to kill the `MyWebApplication.exe` in task manager on the web server. However since I only have access to that server through a shared directory this is not possible.

With `ASP.NET 4` websites  I don't have this problem.

With `ASP.NET CORE RC1` I also didn't have the problem as it was using `dnx` though the `HTTPPlatformHandler` which allowed me to copy the site without having to kill the `dnx.exe`. I just had to touch the `web.config` and the site would restart.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to copy over/publish a new changed version of a site that had already been deployed (Either FTP or via shared folder access)?
2. Is there a way to stop the website e.g. unload the `MyWebApplication.exe` from memory on the web server either via FTP or via shared folder access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ERROR_FILE_IN_USE` error is an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/238) on github

Simply delete the web.config the publish directory before publishing.

Without a web.config the site will automatically stop and unload the files from memory and will stop anyone from loading the site into memory again accessing the URL.

Another workaround is to copy an app_offline.htm to your publish directory which should work as well. [Link](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/141)

Comment: Deleting the Web.config first worked great for me. I was able to make it part of my release pipeline in VSTS, thanks to the Delete Files task.

Answer (score 1):

I decided this issue by stopping my web app on a hosting. After it all had been succesfully published.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your **publish profile**:

```
<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

According to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3719